# How to store multiple selected values in dropdown list in mysql in different cells

Tags: php, mysql

The following code storing selected values in single cell in database,can anyone help how can we store in multiple cells .Thanks

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
     Select your favourite game:<br/>
     <select name="game[]" multiple="multiple">
     <option>Football</option>
     <option>Volleyball</option>
     <option>Badminton</option>
      <option>Cricket</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
      </body>
       </html>

     <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
           {
             $query=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
             mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
             $choice=implode(',',$_POST['game']);
             $choice1=mysql_real_escape_string($choice);
             mysql_query("insert into tb values('','$choice1')");
           } 
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a basic [INSERT query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_%28SQL%29).

For example, change:

```
insert into tb values('','$choice1')
```

To something like:

```
INSERT INTO TB (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('$choice1', '$choice2', '$choice3')
```

Comment: Here the selected values are storing in one row cell with commas,what i want is the selected values should be stored in different row cells not in columns .  Thanks for your reply